# DRF returns empty csv, but json is ok

Tags: django, csv, django-rest-framework, export-to-csv

I am using djangorestframework-csv in my DRF API and i try to specify csv correctly, so user can get correct table (with default settings user will get a table where all objects are specified in 1 row).

**views.py**

```
class MyCSVRenderer(CSVRenderer):
    header = ['wmi', 'country']

class CarCertainView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
    lookup_field = 'wmi'
    renderer_classes = tuple(api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES) + (MyCSVRenderer,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        wmi = self.kwargs.get('key', None)
        print(wmi)
        cars = Car.objects(wmi=wmi.upper())
        content = [{'wmi': car.wmi,
                    'country': car.country}
                   for car in cars]
        return content
```

But here is the problem: if i choose json render in browser, its ok:

```
        "mark": null,
        "wmi": "VSA",
        "add_cod": null,
        "manufacturer": null,
        "mark_owner": null,
        "country_code": null,
        "country": "Испания",
```

(i didn't specified all fields yet, but fields specified in MyCSVRenderer(CSVRenderer) class are correct in JSON response). But when i choose to request CSV there is only

```
wmi,country
,
```

Documentation used: https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv